# How to make multiple arguments into 1

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, args

So I want to have my code be able to take the last set of arguments as one sentence. My code currently is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const { User, ClientUser, GuildMember, TeamMember, Message} = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "USER", "REACTION"]});

module.exports = {
name: 'report',
description: "report a naughty person",

async execute(message, args, Discord, client){ 

const guild = message.guild   

const reason = args.splice(1)

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1ed700')
    .setTitle('Report \n')
    .setDescription(`Person who reported ${message.author} \n`
        + `Channel reported in: ${message.channel}\n`
        + `Person reported: ${args[0]} \n` //The second argument
        + `Reason reported: ${reason}`) // The third argument
     

let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
message.channel.send(`<@&${process.env.DUMMY_ROLE}>`);

}};
```

The issue being is the output makes the final set of arguments have commas in between. So like if I do the command:

> -report @BubGum   for being to cool!

it responds:

> Person who reported @AaronieYT
>
> reported in: #test-channel
>
> Person reported: @BubGum
>
> Reason reported: for,being,to,cool!
>
> @Dummy mod

I want the reasons to have no commas but just be spaces.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) returns a string joining the array elements by a comma. You can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a string separated by spaces.

```
`Reason reported: ${reason.join(' ')}`
```

Answer (score 0):

## [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) vs [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

### [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

[`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString), simply speaking, converts an array to a string by calling `this.join(',')` (see [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)).

`<this>.prototype.toString()` is called when integrating a non-string into a string, as seen here:

```js
class MyCoolClass {
    constructor() {
        this.coolValue = 'some cool value';
    }
    
    toString() {
        console.log('MyCoolClass: toString called');
        return `[MyCoolClass: ${this.coolValue}]`;
    }
}

console.log('creating instance')
const obj = new MyCoolClass();
console.log(`Instance: ${obj}`); // convert obj to string
```

As you can see above, we can create our own `toString` functions, on our  own objects!

Quote from MDN:

> #### Description
>
> Every object has a `toString()` method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the `toString()` method is inherited by every object descended from `Object`. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, `toString()` returns "`[object type]`", where *`type`* is the object type. The following code illustrates this:
>
> ```js
> const o = new Object();
> o.toString(); // returns [object Object]
> ```

### [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

This method takes an array and converts it into a string.

Calling it with `(['foo', 'bar'], ', ')` returns `"foo, bar"`, etc.

### Result

Just do this :)

```js
`Reason reported: ${reason.join(' ')}`
```

<sup>i have managed to fry my own brain</sup>